# catkin_make error in Groovy

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed groovy and I am trying to configure my installation, I have sourced the setup.bash file however when trying to configure my catkin workspace gives me error. When I try catkin_make inside catkin_ws, I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/catkin_make", line 19, in <module>
    from catkin.init_workspace import init_workspace
ImportError: No module named init_workspace
```

Any help folks ? If rosbuild was available on groovy - I guess I would have gladly used that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51325/catkin_make-error-in-groovy/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-01-02**:
By the way a lot of packages are still using rosbuild in groovy.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-02**:
@Dirk Thomas So ! catkin is not essential for groovy -- I CAN use rosbuild ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-03**:
Yes, rosbuild works fine with groovy.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-03**:
@joq Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have likely another version of catkin on your PYTHONPATH i.e. from Fuerte. You should retry it from a "clean" shell without sourcing Fuerte before (or in your bashrc).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-02**:
@Dirk Thomas YES ! You are right -- I had sourced Morse into my ROS Fuerte using another PYTHONPATH -- I have rectified my .bashrc -- everything is cool now !!!!